# Validation errors W3C, Grayscale

Tags: css, wordpress, validation, w3c, grayscale

I have checked my site with W3C validators (http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) and they found the following errors:

---

```
URI: /wp-content/plugins/wp-accessibility/toolbar/css/a11y.css?ver=4.0.1

Lines: 109 .desaturated Property filter doesn't exist: grayscale(100%)

115 .desaturated Property filter doesn't exist: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333
0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale")

116 .desaturated Property filter doesn't exist: gray
```

---

1. I am using  WordPress & WP Accessibility plugin.
2. I need to have the grayscale converter to my site for Disabled Persons.
3. My site has to pass W3C validation.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks again.

Ever grateful

Comment: Please refer plugin author reply here about that w3c error :https://wordpress.org/support/topic/validation-errors-in-w3c-grayscale

Comment: Reply from: Joe Dolson, Plugin Author!

WP Accessibility uses a lot of browser-specific or experimental CSS to enable some of those features. They aren't anything to worry about; if they don't exist in a particular browser, they'll be ignored.